# Detect C++ memory leaks in VSCode using g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, memory-leaks

I'm surprised but I cannot find examples of how to detect memory leaks in a C++ program using VSCode and compiling with g++  Though I will grant that it's been over 18 years since I've actively developed in that language.  Just trying VSCode and want to see if I can do the basics.  If someone has a simple tutorial or example of getting this to work, detecting a simple leak, I would appreciate it.

Comment: On Windows or Linux?

Comment: I don’t have an answer. But if you’ve been out of C++ for 18 years, this may blow your mind, but memory leaks just aren’t an issue most of the time. Just never ever write `new` and instead use `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` or just `std::vector`. If you have a legacy codebase to deal with, my sympathies.

Comment: @ArtemRazin On windows.  I did see how to get the leaks using the cl compiler.

Comment: @Ben that is awesome!!!  No legacy codebase, just mucking around with this as my son is learning C in college and it brings back memories. And coding is fun!

Comment: Yeah, in our commercial codebase the only place we use `new` is placement `new` and `std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(x))` in a `Foo` member function when `Foo(x)` is a private c'tor. I believe we never call `delete` or `delete[]`. If you do that and never call `.release()`, the only way to leak is to make a shared-pointer cycle.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I have not heard about built-in memory leak detection in GCC on Windows (at the same time, CRT in VC++ has some kind of detection). Visual Studio Code itself doesn't have a tool to detect leaks, but probably you might be interested in how my Deleaker deals with leaks: https://www.deleaker.com/blog/2022/03/14/memory-leak-detection-tool-for-mingw/